# Returning objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following variable:

```
var tags = [{name:'Bold', key:'b'}, { name: 'Italic', key:'i'}]
```

Then, in order to get the correct tag I am working on I built a function:

```
function getCurrentTag(tagType) {
    $.each(tags, function() {
        if (tagType==this.name) {
            return this;
        }
    });
}
```

And in the main scope I call it:

```
currentTag = getCurrentTag('Bold');
```

But currentTag is always "undefined".

How can I fix this?

Gidi

Comment: And this is why "use jquery" is not the great panacea it's claimed to be. Javascript works all by itself sometimes.

Comment: jQuery is a library, not a complete language.

Answer (score 6):

```
function getCurrentTag(tagType) {
    for(var i = 0, len = tags.length; i < len; i++) {
        if( tags[i].name === tagType )
            return tags[i];
    }
}
```

using jQuerys `.each()` or `for..in` loops to loop over an array is unecessary (slow).
Since `$.each()` applies a callback function per interation you are returning that value to this anonymous function. You never return from `getCurrentTag()`

Answer (score 1):

You never return the result of `$.each()`.

Comment: Also, further processing on the output of the $.each function will be required. jAndy's way should suffice

Answer (score 1):

Use a native javascript function. No need to use jQuery here.

```
var tags = [{name:'Bold', key:'b'}, { name: 'Italic', key:'i'}],
    getCurrentTag = function (tags, name) {
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < tags.length; += 1) {
            if (tags[i].name === name) {
                return tags[i];
            }
        }
        return False;
    }


 getCurrentTag(tags, 'Bold');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use an array? It would be so much cleaner with a simple object of name value pairs.

```
var tags = {'Bold':'b','Italic':'i'};
function getCurrentTag(tagType) {
    return tags[tagType] || null;
}
```

All of that looping with your way of doing it will be slow: